# Show only the most Recent Item Created

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter

I'm currently looking to create a view that only shows the most recent item created.

I have a list that calculates weekly reports and i want to allow the user to have direct access to editing the most recent report (the most recent item created)

I can't seem to find a way to filter and show only 1 list item. Or even if it is possible to allow a dialog box to target the most recent item ID and directly allow you to edit it that way.

My logic at the moment is to create a view that limits the item to the most recent, then create a link to a datasheet that will allow you to directly edit the item.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a view.
- Set the Sort to Modified and descending.
- Expand Item Limit and set it to 1, and select "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount"

Comment: Much obliged Mike, spot on solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this following the below steps:

1. navigate to `List Settings` under `views` section - click `Create view`
   [image]
2. enter the view name and select the desired columns
3. under `Sort` tab , select the `ID` column and select `Show items in descending order` (to get the most recent item created).

[image]

4. under the `item limit` tab enter the `Number of items to display:` as 1 and choose `Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount`.

[image]
 5. Click `Ok` to save

Comment: Something so simple yet I couldn't figure it out! Much obliged for the help!

Comment: no problem :) glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Most recent is a **rubbery** expression that not has specific criteria, **So** you can't create a view to getting **exactly** the most recently created or modified items,

---

**An alternative solution** is to filter by `Modified` and `Created` is greater than

```
[Today] - X
```

> Where **X** is the number of days, you can change it as you like

[image]

**Then** sort the `Modified` and `Created` **descending**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, appreciate the help. It was answered in the previous post, the list has new items created automatically each week so I only need to be able to see the most recently created item.

Comment: @cod3r_jim No Problem, but have you tried the mentioned solution?, the sort section should satisfy your requirements and you can limit it to a number of days as I mentioned! anyway, great to find the good solution that matches your requirements :)